# How do you print a line that has words that the user has inputed?

Tags: python

```
prob = input("Please enter your problem?")
words = set(prob.split())

file=open('solutions.txt')
line=file.readlines()
if ("smashed") or ("screen") or ("dropped") in words:
    print (line[0])
elif ("wet") or ("water") in words:
    print (line[6])
else:
    print("sorry")
```

The problem with this code is that it just prints the top line of the text file

Here is results:

```
>>> 
============== RESTART: C:\Users\bb\Desktop\completed - Copy.py ==============
Please enter your problem?smashed
your screen is smashed

>>> 
============== RESTART: C:\Users\bb\Desktop\completed - Copy.py ==============
Please enter your problem?wet
your screen is smashed

>>> 
============== RESTART: C:\Users\bb\Desktop\completed - Copy.py ==============
Please enter your problem?bntuib
your screen is smashed

>>>
```

As you can see it only displays the top line of the code no matter what the user inputs.

Comment: `if ("smashed") or ("screen") or ("dropped") in words:` is not what you want here. `if ("smashed")` will always evaluate to `True`. you want: `if "smashed" in words or "screen" in words or "dropped" in words:` (and fix the `elif` accordingly

Comment: @UnholySheep THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with your first `if` condition.

Try the following instead :

```
check_list = ["smashed", "screen", "dropped"] # Words to check

if any(w_ in words for w_ in check_list): # Checks that at least one conditions returns True
     print (line[0])
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok there's quite a few to see here, let's go one by one:

1. `if` statements take an expression that can be simplified to a boolean (True/False). Separate different *statements* by or/and to achieve stricter logic.
   If I want to see if any of the following words are inside a list, for example:

   ```
   #  (            )    (                )    (                )
   if 'wet' in words or 'smashed' in words or 'dropped' in words:
     ...
   ```
2. Since this is getting redundant, we can try to make it a little more flexible (and scalable).

   ```
   words = ['wet', 'smashed', 'dropped']
   if any(word in words for word in cur_line):
       ...
   ```
3. And then we need to make sure this happens for every line, so we should run through each line and apply the same logic...

   ```
   words = ['wet', 'smashed', 'dropped']
   for cur_line in line:
       if any(word in words for word in cur_line):
           print cur_line
   ```